# I have code to create a button type in Xamarin. Is there a way I can pass in a binding parameter?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's the code that I have:

**C# template class**

```
public class PopupOKButton : Button
{
    public PopupOKButton()
    {
        BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        Text = "OK";
        SetDynamicResource(TextColorProperty, "PopUpOkColor");
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;
    }
}
```

**Where it's used:**

```
var ok = new PopupOKButton();
ok.SetBinding(PopupOKButton.CommandProperty, "OKCmd");
ok.SetBinding(PopupOKButton.IsEnabledProperty, "OKEnabled");
```

Is there a way that I could change the definition of PopupOKButton to accept the binding parameters so it could be called like this:

```
var ok = new PopupOKButton("OKCmd", "OKEnabled" );
```

Comment: I would question why you'd want to do this. If you want to add bindings to your custom control you would need to add a static `BindableProperty` and an underlying field (plus an OnPropertyChanged method if needed). I would suggest reading the custom controls on a big repo such as the XamarinCommunityToolkit for the best practises in terms of building custom UI controls: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/src/CommunityToolkit/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit/Views/AvatarView/AvatarView.shared.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never tried it, but I assume this would work

```
public PopupOKButton(string Command, string Enabled) : this()
{
    this.SetBinding(PopupOKButton.CommandProperty, Command);
    this.SetBinding(PopupOKButton.IsEnabledProperty, Enabled);
}

public PopupOKButton()
{
    BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
    Text = "OK";
    SetDynamicResource(TextColorProperty, "PopUpOkColor");
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;
}
```

Comment: I believe so also, Maybe better to invoke the default ctor to avoid code duplication `public PopupOKButton(string Command, string Enabled) : this()` only if inteded to keep the parameterless constructor.

Comment: @Cfun - can you explain what you mean with an example. Thanks

Comment: expanded my example to include @Cfun suggestion